# Lifetime of the pointers

Tags: c++

I was watching the video of Symbio C++ Seminar with Herb Sutter - (Thrill of a) Lifetime 20.6.2016,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7b75rcHg7z0&t=917s

The following code  has been written from the video 11::24.
p1, p2, and p3 pointers must be invalidated when the scope goes out.
It must give error when trying to dereference the pointers.

I'm using online https://wandbox.org/ environment. Both gcc and clang is giving the following results. Which must be wrong.

Can someone check the same code on Visual Stdio.

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int* p1 = nullptr; int* p2 = nullptr; int* p3 = nullptr; 

int main() {
    {
        int i = 1;
        struct MyStruct { char a; int i; char c;} s = {'a', 2, 'c'};
        array<int,7> arr = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
        p1 = &i;
        p2 = &s.i;
        p3 = & arr[2];
        *p1 =*p2= *p3 = 42;
        cout << *p1 << *p2 << *p3 << endl;
    }
    *p1 = 1; // This must give error
    *p2 = 2;
    *p3 = 3;
    cout << *p1 << *p2 << *p3 << endl;
}
```

This is the output:

```
424242
123
```

Comment: Hm? p1, p2, p3 have global scope, since they are outside of all functions, don't they?

Comment: `nullptr` is not C.

Comment: Why do you think they must give an error? I refuse to believe that Herb Sutter would claim such a thing.

Comment: Herb Sutter doesn't say this will result in an error when you run the program. But he says that the cppcheck tool will detect this problem.

Comment: Herb Sutter specifically states that "compilers of today don't catch these cases". They're _logic errors_, and the code is **syntactically legal**. So I'm not sure what the point of your question is. (_Note this question risks moving into "off-topic" territory as looking for a list of compilers that support these checks._)

Comment: @molbdnilo : Actually I was waiting run time error or crash. Not the result of 1,2,3;  What is weird the results are exactly what must not be true.

Comment: @SabetayToros That's just a side effect of the implementation details (the memory remains untouched higher up on the stack). The compilers don't waste time with any additional machine instructions on implementations that trigger run-time errors. But this is the entire point of ***undefined behaviour***: the code _might_ behave "intuitively" (or seem to work correctly); it _might_ simply produce random results; it _might_ produce a run-time error; or as Bathsheba points out it _might_ eat your cat.

Answer (score 9):

The behaviour of the code is *undefined*.

After the first `cout` statement, the pointers are *dangling*. They were pointing to variables that had automatic storage duration, and are now out of scope.

A C++ compiler is **not required** to issue a diagnostic (a dangling pointer cannot always be identified at compilation time), although some will warn you if you have the appropriate flags set. You can cut down the source of the undefined behaviour to

```
int main()
{
    int* p;
    {
        int n;
        p = &n;
    }
    *p = 0; // oops
}
```

Comment: No the compilers does not warn. I was asking can someone test this code on Visual Studio.

Comment: @SabetayToros: I tested it, and the compiler ate my cat.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++17 also fails to detect the undefined behavior, and gives the same output.

Comment: That's rather a comment, isn't it? I suppose you entered your text into the wrong textbox ;-)

Comment: @Michael Walz - The  question was, "Can someone check the same code on Visual Studio.?" I guess technically the correct answer is, "Yes."

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking it does answer the actual question; but it goes nowhere towards resolving OP's underlying confusion. (Basically OP asked the wrong question.)